# mapping n x m image to 256 x m matrix according to its pixel intensity

Tags: python, image-processing, mapping

Let say I have an image **n x m**, and I do want to map it to **256 x m** new matrix. All the elements in the **j** th column of the original image will be the **j** th column of the new matrix, but elements will be distributed to row according to its pixel intensity `range(0, 255)` as its new index **i**. -matching index **i** in the new column **j** will be summed up then divide by `new_column.max()`.- In google search this representation can be found under various keywords such as, lumetri scopes, video scopes, video waveform, RGB parade, depending on which software is named it. I do not know what actually is the correct definition of it. Hence, I was not able to done a proper research on it. In fact, I couldn't go further than video editing blogs. It is a bit confusing to be honest. But, I did achieve it using two nested `for` loops

```
r = #image red channel 1080 x 1080
scope = np.zeros((256, 1080))

for e, i in enumerate(r):
  for k, j in enumerate(i):
    intensity = r[k][e] 
    scope[intensity][e] += 1
        
  scope[::, e] /= scope[::, e].max()
```

,and it takes approximately 5 sec to calculate just for **1080 x 1080** image, not even mention to multiple channels. I am wondering if there is more quicker way to achieve this with numpy, scipy or other possible tools.

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1G5J.png)

Comment: You are computing a histogram per image line. Try using a predefined histogram function from any image processing library. You’d still have the loop over columns.

Comment: Kindly share your input image as well.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yeah, thanks mate, it makes so much more sense now.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've just picked an arbitrary image, didn't consider that is relevant. Because output is also an arbitrary image that I've found in online. But the way Chris told, solved my issue, thanks anyway.